# How to create spacing between Charts and Legends in Chart.js

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I'm sorry for my poor English.
I want to Create Spacing between Graphs and Legends in Chart.js.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

The code is as follows.

ChartBox.vue

```vue
<template>
 <Chart :chartData="chartItems" :options="chartOptions"/>
</template>

<script>
 import Chart from './ChartBox/ChartBox.js'
 export default {
  components: {
   Chart
  },
  data() {
   return {
    chartItems: {
        labels: ["12月", "1月", "2月", "3月", "4月", "5月", "6月", "7月", "8月", "9月", "10月", "11月"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "月ごとの数",
          data: [9500, 12000, 19000, 15000, 9500, 5000, 10000, 14000, 9500, 8000, 4500, 7000],
          backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
        }]
      },

      chartOptions: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          }]
        }
      }
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

ChartBox.js

```js
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
export default {
 extends: Bar,
 props: ["chartData", "options"],
 mounted() {
  this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way. What you can do is disable the legend and use the `generateLabels` function to get al the labels and make a custom legend https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration